# Intersect variable in data frame grouped and subset by different variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following variables : `Source`, `Name`, `Date` and `Value`.
I want to, using the pipe operator (`%>%`) and `dplyr`, find the intersection of 'Dates' variable for each 'Name' between the different 'Sources'.

Here is and example data frame:
[Example data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPb6a.png)

So, for the Name `a`, the following date vectors are present for each of the `Source` values:

[Date vectors for name 'a' per 'Source'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpkve.png)

I only want to keep the records (rows) where the dates intersect for a given `Name` by comparing between different `Source` values, so in this case the intersecting dates among all `Source` subsets for `Name` with value `a` are: 01.01.2019, 03.01.2019, 05.01.2019.

I thought about grouping by the 'Name' variable and then using the `dplyr::intersect` but I cannot come up with a way on how to subset the `df` by the 'Source' and supply the subsets to the `dplyr::intersect` function to the intersection between the different 'Date' vector subsets (determined by the 'Source' label):

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(Name) %>% dplyr::intersect(Here the subsets of df should be provided as arguments)
```

Alternatively, is there a neat way of writing this using `inner_join` or some other `join` ?

Comment: Please provide some toy data. Otherwise it is hard to follow your question.

Comment: Hi @Cettt , I added an example data frame with a desired outcome.

Comment: You added a screenshot, its hard to work with a screenshot. Rather use `dput(mydata)` and post the result inside your question.
Also post the desired output in the same form.

Comment: Sorry, still new to this thing. But I managed to figure it out and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so the following syntax does want I want:

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(Source.Count = n_distinct(Source)) %>% dplyr::group_by(Name, Date) %>% dplyr::filter(n() == Source.Count) %>% dplyr::select(Source, Name, Date, Value)
```

The reason I'm creating the `Source.Count` variable is that after grouping the `n_distinct` function wasn't functioning properly and didn't give the appropriate number of Sources for each row. Then I group by `Name` and `Date` and with the `n()` function I count the number of instance of a given combination of `Name` and `Date`. If the number of instances is equal to the number of distinct `Source` labels, this means that this combination of `Name` and `Date` is present for all `Source` subsets.